# Heroku SSL error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ssl-doctor.heroku.com

Tags: ssl, heroku

I am working on a Heroku app and am trying to deploy the domain with SLL. (I bought a custom domain from Bluehost). I have 3 files for my SLL:

a .cert.file
a .cabundle file
a .key file
So I typed the command
heroku certs:update mycert.cert mykey.key
I am getting this error:

````
! ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ssl-doctor.heroku.com```
````

Answer (score 0):

Update your heroku cli by running `heroku update`

Comment: What is the latest version? This fails for us, even after completely removing and re-installing heroku CLI to `heroku/7.59.0 darwin-x64 node-v12.21.0`

Comment: @prototype you can see releases here : https://github.com/heroku/cli/releases

Comment: aha, thanks! I was wondering why update didn't work but  it looks like the code still references a domain that no longer exists https://github.com/heroku/cli/search?q=ssl-doctor

Answer (score 0):

Add the flag `--bypass` as in

```
heroku certs:update mycert.cert mykey.key --bypass
```

From https://github.com/heroku/cli/pull/1789